# Is it possible to update data owner for an Asset in Purview?

Tags: python, azure

I'm tasked to update assets data owner and I'm trying to use it using the purview client sdk.
This is how I tried but it kept blank on purview.

```
def bind_data_owner_to_asset(owner, asset_guid):
      try:
        return purview_client.partial_update_entity(
          guid=asset_guid,
          attributes={
              "owner": owner
          }
        )
      except:
        return None
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it on the API, using the Update Entity endpoint and posting the Contacts:Owner:[{id:sdfsdfsd-sdfsdf}]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).